# Cannot test with JUnit, Maven and Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit

I'm using Spring 4.3.0, Junit 4.12 and trying to run this test with Maven:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("spring-test.xml")
public class SpringTest {

    @Test
    public void testIt() {}
    
}
```

As result, I get this error:

> initializationError(SpringTest)  Time elapsed: 0.005 sec  <<< ERROR!
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate [class org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;

Can anybody help me pointing out a possible root cause for this problem?

---

Here are my spring dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: most probably spring-test library version is not 4.3.0

Comment: @hoaz: Nope, this is not the case.

Comment: Can you provide full stack trace?

Comment: @hoaz The one printed is the full stack trace. I know it's short, but that's the only stack trace I get.

Comment: And what is the version of spring-beans? Can you do mvn dependency:tree?

Comment: put your whole pom in the question or at least the dependencies and preferably also the output of `mvn dependency:tree`.

Comment: @hoaz, M.Deinum Here is where the problem resides. I'll have a closer look on this tomorrow. The POM has some "hidden" dependecies. Thanks for guiding me in the right direction.